# Google GCP Trace: Trace with nested user functions information

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stack-trace

Currently this is the picture I have when analysing GCP trace. It is useful but we need to have a deeper analysis on some spots we want to improve.

[image: Standard Trace without nested user function info]

What we would like to do is to have something like this

> ```
>   | vi/route/r   
>      | function abc (75 ms)
>        | redis-hget (1 ms)
>        | datastore (69 ms)
>           | function cde (30 ms)
>               | ...
> ```

We have tried a lot but we didn't find further documentation regarding the concepts of GCP trace, rather only detailed API calls.

Here is our POC

Entry Level

```
require('@google-cloud/trace-agent').start({
    projectId: 'my-project',
    keyFilename: './my-credentials.json',
    stackTraceLimit: 0,
});

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const toSecondLevel = require('./controllers/home');
const initController = require('./controllers/init');

app.post('/poc/', bodyParser.json(), async (req, res) => {

    const trace = require('@google-cloud/trace-agent').get()

    const rootSpan = trace.getCurrentRootSpan();
    const { requestType } = req.body;

    rootSpan.addLabel('Root - First Level' , requestType);
    await toSecondLevel(rootSpan, req, res);

    rootSpan.endSpan(new Date());
    res.send('Hello World! ===> ' + requestType);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Second Level

```
const toThirdLevel = require('../services/home')


const secondLevelFunction = async (rootSpan, req, res) => {

    await secondLevelFunctionPromise(rootSpan);
}


const secondLevelFunctionPromise = (rootSpan) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const span = rootSpan.createChildSpan({ name: 'secondLevelFunction' });
    setTimeout(async () => {
        console.log('secondLevelFunction', span.getTraceContext())
        span.addLabel('Should be nested to Root?', 'NOT nested');
        await toThirdLevel(rootSpan, new Date());

        span.endSpan(new Date())
        resolve();
    }, 2400);
})

module.exports = secondLevelFunction;
```

And the third Level

```
const thirdLevelFunction = (rootSpan, parametro1) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const span = rootSpan.createChildSpan({ name: 'thirdLevelFunction' });
    setTimeout(() => {
        span.addLabel('thirdLevelFunction', 'not nested as well')
        console.log(span.getTraceContext())

        span.endSpan(new Date());
        resolve();
    }, 1392);
})

module.exports = thirdLevelFunction;
```

The problems / Conceptual questions:

1- No `Span` is Nested in the POC

2- All the Spans has `getTraceContext()`. Can I use this to some how nest my Spans?

3- Is it possible to make what I am intending to do? (A- Nest my Span and B- Nest into the same tree showed in the first image?

4- Class RootSpan extends Span. But I can't have any different behaviour from this.

Answer (score 1):

Now it is working. What is needed (`typescript` to better understanding):

```
import * as traceAgent from '@google-cloud/trace-agent';
const trace: traceAgent.PluginTypes.Tracer = traceAgent.get();
const span: TraceSpan = this.trace.createChildSpan(options);
...
span.addLabel('property',yourContent);
spam.endSpan(getDate());
```

Important to notice that traceAgent.get() is a factory and the plugin manages to give it coherence on the order of events even if several threads are asking for new spans.

I highly recommend:

1. use the interfaces provided as the documentation is poor. Reading
   the interfaces and actual code give you better understanding
2. Make a Wrapper to your span so you can create an indirection much more tied
   to your needs. Now I can open a span with a label, close with a
   label, add an object so the I can create a label based on the
   object.

[image: Now Working: Actual code and RPC calls]